# Project with different modules but main module in root

Tags: go, module, database-connection, go-gorm

I want to create a library in Go, a utility library for [Gorm](https://gorm.io/index.html). The thing is that to create tests, I need also a driver (like postgresql, or mysql), but I don't want those drivers to be included in the go.mod of the "main" project. I know in Java it's possible to include libraries only for test folder, but I understand this is not possible in Go. So I was wondering whether it would be possible to have like a "submodule" inside the project in which that submodule would contains the tests that uses different drivers. So basically to have something like:

myproject:

- my_library.go
- test_module/

  - my_library_postgres_test.go // testing the functionality of my_library.go using the postgres driver
  - my_library_mysql_test.go // testing the functionality of my_library.go using the mysql driver
  - go.mod // including the main project along with the postgres and mysql driver
- go.mod // main go.mod that contains the gorm dependency (without any driver)

Comment: Yes it's possible to have a submodule.

Comment: so I would create a folder, then call go mod init, and in that go.mod, how can I reference the "parent"module?

Comment: "I don't want those drivers to be included in the go.mod of the 'main' project." Why?

Comment: @Volker, (this is maybe a mistake in my side), because then the project that import my library needs to also import those drivers since they are part of my dependencies, right?

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#faqs--multi-module-repositories

Comment: Can you explain why you think any code that imports some packages from your project "needs to also import those drivers" just because their versions are listed in go.mod? Do you think these imports happen somehow "automatically"? Or do you think if someone uses package A from your project but doesn't manually import everything listed in go.mod it won't build? Take a careful look at go.mod: It contains modules, not packages.

Comment: The go.mod file "pins" version of modules you import. That's all. It is not a list of "please include everything here". The whole idea of a "test dependency" is pretty strange imho, albeit being dead common in different technologies.